# how to override /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Random.php

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, overrides, rwd-theme

I have been trying to override the Random.php file and have looked at [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) and [another method here](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/).  When I do the change on the core file the change takes effect immediately, but when I created the override, the modification do not take effect.

I am trying to override 
`/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Random.php`. I have created `/app/code/local/MyFolder/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Random.php` (the modified file).

I have also changed the class name in my override file, to `class MyFolder_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

I can't figure out how to properly modify `app/etc/config.xml` file? This is what I have so far.

```
<config>
 <global>
    ...
    <models>
    ...
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list>MyFolder_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random</product_list>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>           
 </global>
</config>
```

OK it's now functioning.
Changed from:

```
<rewrite>
    <product_list>MyFolder_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random</product_list>
</rewrite>
```

To:

```
<rewrite>
    <product_list_random>MyFolder_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random</product_list_random>
</rewrite>
```

Now I am not sure if there are any other places that needs updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite path should be `global/blocks/catalog/rewrite/product_list_random`.

Also, you should *not* be making this entry in *`app/etc/config.xml`*, because this change will be lost in an upgrade. Better to register a new module in *`app/etc/modules`* and add this configuration directive to your module's config file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By registering you mean, create a file called `MyFolder.xml` in `app/etc/module/`?  And adding this configuration means, adding the above: `<config><blocks><catalog><rewrite><product_list_random>MyFolder_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random</product_list_random</rewrite></catalog></blocks></config>` to `app/etc/module/MyFolder.xml`? Kindly clarify.

Comment: I did exactly as explained above, but I am NOT getting the changes!  But as soon as I place the directives back in `app/etc/config.xml` it starts working again.  Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Clear the configuration cache and see if it works. Also, the config directive should go in your module's config.xml file

Comment: Cleared all cache.  No it is not happening for me.  Yes, I do have the `<config><blocks><catalog><rewrite><product_list_random>MyFolder_Catalog_Block_P‌​roduct_List_Random</product_list_random</rewrite></catalog></blocks></config>` saved as `MyFolder.xml` in this folder -> `app/etc/module/MyFolder.xml`.